# PHP json_encode token_get_all

Tags: php, json, tokenize

I want to return the PHP [token_get_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) function as JSON.

I also want token_get_all to pass the token through the [token_name()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-name.php) function to get its name.

I have tried various different methods but none produce the results I need.

I'm wanting to use this information in JavaScript, I want to be able to call tokens.tokenName for example.

I think I need something like the following example:

```
{

 "tokenName":"T_COMMENT","tokenValue":"# some comment","tokenLine":"1"
 "tokenName":"T_VARIABLE","tokenValue":"$some_variable","tokenLine":"2"
}
```

I've tried to put the token_get_all() function directly through the [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function, as well as playing around with various arrays and the results are not what I wanted.

This is the latest incarnation of the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['code']) || (isset($_GET['code']))) {

    if (isset($_POST['code'])) {
        $code = $_POST['code'];
    } elseif (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $code = $_GET['code'];
    }

    $tokens = array();
    $tokenName = array();
    $tokenValue = array();
    $tokenLine = array();

    foreach(token_get_all($code) as $c) {

        if(is_array($c)) {
            array_push($tokenName, token_name($c[0])); // token name
            array_push($tokenValue, $c[1]); // token value
            array_push($tokenLine, $c[2]); // token line number

        } else {
            array_push($tokenValue, $c); // single token, no value or line number
        }

    }

    // put our token into the tokens array
    array_push($tokens, $tokenName);
    array_push($tokens, $tokenValue);
    array_push($tokens, $tokenLine);

    // return our tokens array JSON encoded
    echo(json_encode($tokens));


}
```

Thank you,

Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you actually want to do is generate a list of dictionaries. For that you should prefer ordinary array appending instead of `array_push`:

```
foreach(token_get_all($code) as $c) {

    $tokens[] =
        array(
            "tokenName" => token_name($c[0]),
            "tokenValue" => $c[1],
            "tokenLine" => $c[2]
        );

}
```

Saves you a few temporary variables and is easier to read. It would give you a result such as:

```
[    
   {"tokenName":"T_COMMENT","tokenValue":"# some comment","tokenLine":"1"},
   {"tokenName":"T_VARIABLE","tokenValue":"$some_variable","tokenLine":"2"}
]
```